# get Javascript to not appear as code on the page

Tags: javascript

I don't know much about this, just having recently started with JavaScript, so simple language would be greatly appreciated.

Whenever I insert JavaScript on a page, it appears in the preview as text on the page and when I update my site it also appears this way. How would I fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might be not inserting javascript in <script> </script> tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to inject JavaScript into a page.

Inline in either the head or body of your html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('this is inline javascript');
</script>
```

Or you can link to an external JavaScript file from the head of your html document.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script>
```

Just remember: if the javascript is an external file, save it with the .js extension.

Comment: Thanks. This is all very useful. It also makes me realize how much I have to learn. Foo instance, I don't even have a good grasp of how you comment something out in javascript. Is there a really good, easily understandable manual online somewhere? I'm gradually learning flash and I'm trying to make a series of overlays for flash-based audio players.

Comment: I would recommend starting off by watching Youtube videos on JavaScript (TheNewBoston has the best series), then I would pick up a book (JavaScript: The Definitive Guide does the best job of explaining advanced concepts).

Answer (score 3):

Do you have it within `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags?

Comment: Thank you. 
I feel a little foolish, but I suspect that I might inadvertently have left that out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a sample of what you are doing for us to help you.

However, you might check that your script declaration looks something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- //html comment hides script from really old browsers

  myVar = resultsFromAMethod();

//-->
</script>
```

Comment: I think it turned out that I hadn't put in the <script type= and </script>, which shows me up pretty clearly as being a real novice. I kind of came across a solution by chance while pasting this line of code for lightbox: <script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox.js"></script>
But you make a very good point -- I'll make sure I paste in the code next time so you don't have to guess. Thank you.